# Wildfly org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, application-server

I am deploying my application on few application server, one of them is the Wildfly 11.0.0.Final. I am using JPA without direct dependencies to Hibernate (just JPA api). I have a persistence.xml file which has a definition for datasource.

When I try to run this application I am getting the following exception when persistence.xml file is being parsed:

> org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

I checked and it seems that I have one dependency which has dependency to org.dom4j with version 2.0.1. I see in JBoss modules that Hibernate module has dependency to org.dom4j:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.classmate"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="org.antlr"/>
    <module name="org.dom4j"/>
    <module name="org.javassist" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.jandex"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.infinispan" services="import" optional="true"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5" services="import"/>
</dependencies>
```

However, it uses dom4j module which is define in JBoss itself and there the version is 1.6.1. I understand that two different versions can cause problems.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to solve it by removing dependency to JBoss dom4j (1.6.1 version)? I tried already with jboss-deployment-structure but it didn't help:
2. It works on JBoss EAP 7.1 but not on Wildfly 11.0.0.Final. What could be the reason?

Comment: You should update your pom dependencies specifically for Wildfly 11 but also can look at https://developer.jboss.org/thread/278669

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do this - I am using the dependent library which contains this newer version of dom4j

Comment: Do you have a requirement on the newer version?

Comment: This library with version 2.1.0 is located under my ear/lib folder. I checked how class loading works on Wildfly 11.0.0 in comparison to JBoss EAP 7.1. In both this class is first loaded from provided 1.6.1 jar. JBoss does not load the newer version. However, Wildfly does and here is the problem